# Subfloor and underlayment sizing for LVP glued down flooring

Tags: flooring, subfloor

I've read many different topics on flooring but haven't seen an answer specific to my questions, so I'll post them here.  Thanks for the help in advance!

The back-story:
I ripped up 40yr old carpet and 3/4" particle board underlayment in the entire house.  Below that I find 1/2" plywood subfloor.
Subfloor has some filler here and there, but is generally in good shape.  Will replace some places that had utilities stubbed thru that are no longer needed, and some rotten places.  Floor joists are 2x14's.

End result:
I'm installing LVP and gluing down. https://www.calibamboo.com/product-longboard-north-shore-attached-pad-vinyl-flooring-7902501001.html
I want the floor to be very ridged and strong.

The questions:  Will installing another layer of 1/2" cdx perpendicularly (glued and screwed) make for a strong, stiff floor? Or would it be better to take up the subfloor and use 23/32" Advantech flooring?
Is it advisable to use an underlayment or plywood prep?

Thank you!

Comment: What is the spacing of the 2x14’s and what is their span?

Comment: Plywood is inherently strong in both directions, however laying a 2nd layer perpendicularly (as you're planning on doing) is good to ensure a minimum overlap of joints.